# How can i get a value from forms.ModelChoiceField in django?

Tags: python, html, django

First of all I want to apologize for my English. It's hard for me to write this question in English, but I didn't find any ideas for my problem on russian sites. So, I want to create a timetable on school-site. In my **models.py** :

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'classes'
        verbose_name_plural = "School_classes"
        verbose_name = "School_class"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name = 'School_classes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lessons(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "lessons"
        verbose_name_plural = "Lessons"
        verbose_name = "Lessons"
    lessons_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes)
    lessons_creationdate = models.DateField()
    lessons_weekcontent = RichTextField()
```

Then, in **forms.py** I have:

```
class LessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        classname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Classes.objects.all(),empty_label="Choose a class",widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'dropdown'}),label="School_classes")
        class Meta:
            model = Lessons
            fields = ('lessons_class',)
```

And in my **views.py**:

```
def ShowTimetable(request):
    LForm = LessonsForm(request.POST or None)
    args = {}
    args['classes'] = Classes.objects.all()
    args['lessons'] = Lessons.objects.all()
    args['showlessons'] = LForm
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST' and LForm.is_valid():
        CurrentClass = LForm.cleaned_data('currentclass', None)
        args['class_name'] = CurrentClass
        args['lessons'] = Lessons.objects.filter(lessons_class = CurrentClass)
        if args['lessons']:

             return render_to_response('Weekcontentpage.html',args )
        else:

             return render_to_response('Weekcontentpage_null.html',args )
    else:
        return render_to_response('myview.html',args )
```

**Finally, in myviews.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form  method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ showlessons }}
  <input type="submit" value="Show timetable">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**In Weekcontentpage.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h4>On request "{{ class_name }}:</h4>
{% for lesson in lessons %}
    <h6>Date:{{ lesson.lessons_creationdate }}</h6>
    <h4>{{ lesson.lessons_weekcontent }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**and in Weekcontentpage_null.html:**
{% extends "base.html" %}

```
{% block content %}

    <h4> On  "{{class_name}}"  is nothing found :( (</h4>


{% endblock content %}
```

Now, after I make a choice in the drop down menu and push 'Show timetable' button, I've just see "None"  and nothing is found :(. I understand that the problem in views.py, so i cant get a value from drop down, but I don't know how can i fix it. So i would appreciate any help. Thanks and sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as with any other field.

The problem is that you have defined a form class, but *you are not using it in any way at all*. Instead of ignoring the form and getting data from `request.POST`, you should be instantiating the form with the POST data, calling `is_valid()` on it, then getting the result from `form.cleaned_data`.

Comment: I've read manuals on djangoprojects.com but after all i cant understand what should i write now ni views.py. I'll try to fix it as you said and now i have: def ShowTimetable(request):
    LForm = LessonsForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and LForm.is_valid():
        CurrentClass = LForm.cleaned_data('currentclass', None)
        args['class_name'] = CurrentClass
        args['lessons'] = Lessons.objects.filter(lessons_class = CurrentClass)
but it works same:( Can you show me how should it lokks like, please?

Comment: Please *update the question* with your code. But where is `currentclass` supposed to be coming  from? Your field is called `classname`.

Comment: I updated the question and now my views.py looks like that. Now after i push the button, i see this kind of error: 'dict' object is not callable. I am sure that i asking silly questions but i cant solve this problem without somebody's help:(

Comment: You've missed the `.get` after `cleaned_data`. And you still haven't addressed my point about the field name.

Comment: Oh, i've got it. Thank you soo much! Can i ask you one more question please?:)

Comment: Sure, but you might want to do it as a separate question.

Comment: I guess its will be more relevant to ask about it here. Why did i have 2 dropdown menus on the page? It works, but i should choose same values in both of this dropdowns. Something wrong with my forms.py? I tried to write {{ showlessons.classname }} instead of {{ showlessons }} in myview.html but it doesn't works then